# How to find depth of tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have class that can have nested same class instances:

```
class SomeClass
{
    List<SomeClass> SomeClasses;
}
```

And... I need to know what is the most high amount in chain `Parent - Children`.

It's like that:
[image]

I so confused about this, so I don't even know how to start doing it. Most likely it can't be done without recursion.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really understand your diagram or what you mean by "most high amount in chain". Given that any `SomeClass` instance forms a tree, perhaps you are looking for the depth of the tree. If that's the case, you would indeed use recursion: write a function `int Depth(SomeClass c)` that returns `1 + SomeClasses.Select(Depth).Concat(new [] { 0 }).Max()`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - Yes, I need depth of the tree. Thanks, I will try yout function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that any SomeClass instance forms a tree, perhaps you are looking for the depth of the tree. If that's the case, you would indeed use recursion: write a function that accepts a `SomeClass` and returns 1 plus the maximum of the list formed by applying itself to the `SomeClasses` list.

Here for example is an implementation in JS:

```js
const depth = ({ things }) => 1 + Math.max(0, ...things.map(depth))

depth({
  things: [
    {
      things: [
        {
          things: []
        },
        {
          things: [
            {
              things: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

// 4
```